# How to add any program in supervisor without restarting it (Supervisor XML-RPC)

Tags: python, python-2.7, xml-rpc, supervisord, xmlrpclib

I have written a program that adds the config file in the conf.d folder of the supervisor now it is being added but I need to restart the supervisor every time. Here is the code..

```
import xmlrpclib

server = xmlrpclib.Server('http://localhost:9001/RPC2')

string='''[program:xyz]
command=path/of/file
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=path/to/error.log
stdout_logfile=path/to/output.log
user=root '''

f=open('/etc/supervisor/conf.d/xyz.conf','w+')
f.write(string)
server.supervisor.reloadConfig()
server.supervisor.startAllProcesses()
server.supervisor.restart()
```

Ther is a method to add the process groups into it

```
server.supervisor.addProcessGroup('xyz')
```

then it says BAD_NAME error.

So the code works but I need to call that supervisor.restart() method and that restarts the supervisor every time I run the code, Is there any way to do it without restarting it ?

Comment: found the bug I was not closing the file so it was reloading the empty file.
aaded 
f.close()
and the job is done without restarting the supervisor \